# how to verify maxminddb geoip md5 checksum?

Tags: geoip

I download maxminddb database file from
    http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz

and download its md5 checksum from
    http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.md5

Then I run
    md5sum GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz

and I found the running result is different from the content in GeoLite2-Country.md5.

Show I verify md5 checksum in this way?

how to verify maxminddb geoip md5 checksum

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, that I should do 
    md5sum GeoLite2-City.mmdb

in other words, unzip the database first, then check md5checksum